# how calculate frequency with pandas from 2 columns and doing a 3d plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, frequency

I'm new in python. 
I would like to calculate frecuency of a file of two columns. This file contain 5 millions of lines or more. 
For example

```
20.735895   0.969697
20.504506   0.969697
20.500563   0.969697
20.901916   0.969697
21.295618   0.969697
21.176620   0.969697
```

my script is this, but it doesn't work

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
array_txt = np.loadtxt("file.txt",usecols=(0, 1))
x = array_txt[:,0]
y = array_txt[:,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[x], 'B':[y]})
print (x)
print (y)
print (df)
count = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size()
print(count)
```

My output should be:

```
20.735895   0.969697  0.65
20.504506   0.969697  0.89
20.500563   0.969697  0.25
```

The result of the third column would be the frecuency. I would like to have this result, to have the variable "Z" for doing a plot 3D in matplotlib, because I don't have idea how calculate Z for a set of values 2D, considering x and y. And be able to do this kind of plot:

[image]

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate the frequency of a file"? Is the frequency information in one of the columns?

Comment: Hi Lepakk, I want calculate the frequency of the two columns, not one by one

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get, what your frequency is supposed to be. But do I get this right, your A and B columns should be the X and Y coordinates in your plot? The Z value is then calculated from the X and Y data? Maybe it would help, if you could provice a bit more information about what your data actually means.

Comment: Yes, A and B columns should be the X and Y coordinates.  The Z value is then calculated from the X and Y data. I want plotting similar to this https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html . I don't know how define Z, I supposed that would be the frecuency, like a histogram but on 3D.

Comment: So is the operation something like Z=(Some function of X) * (Some function of Y) for every row?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that.

Comment: @Hdez _Yes, I suppose that._ You suppose? You wrote _I don't have idea how calculate Z for a set of values 2D, considering x and y_, that's the real issue in my opinion. **How can we help if no one knows what the goal is?** This wouldn't even be a programming question then, no?

Comment: @Hdez: I posted some solution below, that would work, if you want to calculate a value for Z row-wise, that means, just based on values from other columns but in that same row. The function is something arbitrary, and you can adjust it to whatever your function looks like. Still, I agree with AMC, that first you should be clear, what your function is. If you are not sure, we might be able to help you to figure that out, but we need more information about this, so please take some time to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, then this can be simply solved with df.apply

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,2),columns=['A','B'])
df.A=df.A+4
df.B=df.B+1
df['Z']=df.apply(lambda row: np.sqrt(row.A)+row.B**2,axis=1)
```

I generate some random data, and then just apply another column to the dataframe. Using the lambda function, I can operate with the elements from other columns in each row and calculate a value for Z for every row. Afterwards you can plot the data in the way you want, it seems you already have a clear imagination, how that should look like.
I hope, this solves your problem.